# Clean URL's using OpenCart's router class

Tags: routes, opencart

How do you write clean URL's in OpenCart using their built in Router class? Here is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(system) - [F,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  Even after renaming the file from .htaccess.txt to .htaccess and enabling it in the Admin.

Comment: The OpenCart system routing is a mess. I ended almost re-writing the class and adding 20+ Rewrite Rules to my .htaccess file to make it work. The core system has major flaws and downfalls. I would recommend Magento is you have the time to learn the templating system.

Comment: @Torez: I'd happily choose an Opencart flawed rewriting implementation over the abysmal Magento performance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The work is very hard
To modify more than 3 files

```
catalog\controller\common\seo_url.php
catalog\model\tool\seo_url.php
```

Add this line to your file to modify

`$this->load->model('tool/seo_url')`
and used 
`$this->model_tool_seo_url->rewrite()` to rewrite.

Hard to say clearly,the above are only approximate

Answer (score 1):

You can change catalog\controller\common\seo_url.php  and use VQMod to add your own lines of code to it. For example, you can create some class in another file and call that class's members in catalog\controller\common\seo_url.php using VQMod.